# How do I reverse an array in JavaScript while preserving the original value of the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I'm trying to reverse the order of an array using the .reverse() method in JavaScript, but also trying to preserve the original order of elements in the original array. When I save the values into a variable, I end up transposing the elements in the original array as well as creating a new one with the same format. What is the most eloquent way to perform this task?

```
var arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arrayTwo = arrayOne.reverse();
//arrayTwo = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
//arrayOne = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: do you need it actually reversed on a separate variable or could you just iterate backwards from its length property?

Comment: You'd have to make a clone. The reverse method is a mutative method, so the original array gets changed. Simply setting another array to it wont preserve it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722433/javascript-copy-array-to-new-array about the slice method

Comment: More duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666679/making-an-independent-copy-of-a-reversed-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 7):

```
var arrayTwo = arrayOne.slice().reverse();
```

Slice will clone the array

Comment: Yup. Note that it is a shallow copy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: This question would obviously be a duplicate. Next time please find the dup and close. You have the rep to do so

Comment: Thank you @jcubic and Ramón Gil Moreno, I'd give you an upvote for educating me, but as mplungjan put in such a snark manner, while my rep of "ONE" allows me to spend countless hours looking through the hundreds of related questions, it inhibits my ability to return the favor of enlightening me. I appreciate it. Seriously the most annoying thing about Stack Overflow.