# Javascript unbind variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code that copy variable value then change its value.

```js
var a = [{name: 'John Doe'}];
var b = a;

document.write(b[0].name + '<br />');
document.write(a[0].name + '<br /><br />');

b[0].name = 'Jane Doe';

document.write(b[0].name + '<br />');
document.write(a[0].name + '<br />');
```

But somehow that also change first variable value

How do I make variable A to keep its value?

Comment: You have to deeply clone `a`, one way to do it is `var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))`

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722433/javascript-copy-array-to-new-array

Comment: Variable a is being passed into b by reference.  Since a and b have the same reference, whenever you change anything on one it also changes the other.  To prevent this you'll need to do a deep copy of a onto b, copying all of the individual properties.

Comment: Objects (including Arrays) are assigned by reference in JavaScript. You must manually copy them if you need to maintain two separate `.name` values.

Comment: Sorry if its duplicated, I dont know the correct terms when I search the answer before :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just assigning the `a`-reference to `b`. What you may want to do is copying the array so that changes to `a` are not reflected to `b`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript) for the different assignments in JavaScript.

Take also a look at [fastest way to duplicate an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop). It's about the speed of different array copy methods.
Quick answer is:

```
var b = a.slice();
```

The `slice()` method creates a new array with the same elements than the original one. But be careful it's only a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

You could also use the `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`methods for doing a deep copy.